# How can I "bump" my system clock by fractions of a second on macOS for ham radio time keeping needs?

Tags: macos, time, ntp

I'm running Ventura 13.4 on an M2 MacBook Air. I run the FT8 and FT4 digital modes for ham radio.

FT8/4 requires fairly accurate time synchronization. It seems that macOS gets out of sync when waking up from sleep. (See [Time.apple.com sync](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254749768)).

The solution for better time synchronization is to run chrony, or better, the GUI version, chronyControl. (See [Accurate time keeping on an Apple Mac running macOS Big Sur for FT8, FT4 and WSPR](https://qso365.co.uk/2021/04/accurate-time-keeping-on-an-apple-mac-running-macos-big-sur-for-ft8-ft4-and-wspr/))

This has been working well for me, very well. My clock is very accurate. However, I'm still having time-shift issues. Notice that the [time.is](https://time.is/) website says my time is +-0.001 seconds. But look at the left-hand side, the third column is my time shift compared to others, the rest of the world is about 0.8 seconds off.

[image: Screenshot of two windows: the left window shows timings for FT8/FT4 while the right window is the current time according to the website time.is]

Since it is unlikely that the rest of the world is wrong, I must be wrong. Other hams have steered me to the likely culprit: I have an audio latency issue. The audio setup is simple and fixing it is unlikely. So I'd like to be able to bump my system clock by fractions of a second. (Clearly, I'll have to disable chronyControl when I do this!)

Any sort of shell script to read the time and set the time would probably not work well since it would take a fraction of a second to run. I need a better way to do this.

How can I bump my system clock by a specified amount?

Comment: It seems to me that the radio software should handle an offset introduced by lag instead of you miscalibrating your system clock.

Comment: If you are into amateur radio, I am surprised you do not seem to be running your own GPS time server.

Comment: The time server isn't the issue. My time is correct. The audio latency isn't the issue. (And yes, I should get a GPS dongle for time, some day...)

Comment: The software really should, but, it doesn't. It is open source and I suppose I could take a crack at it, but I retired from software dev awhile back. No coding for me anymore.

Comment: I thought Carsten S and Bib were wholly correct, which to me suggests that 'the software' is the problem, and you might try other software…

Comment: 'The software' is wsjtx.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're using `chrony` to synchronize time with NTP servers and managing it with the ChronyControl program. In the ChronyControl Settings window, you can click "Edit Configuration" to edit the `chrony.conf` file.

In here you will find a definition of your time sources (amongst other things). For example it will look like this:

```
server 1.dk.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

You can add a setting like this:

```
offset -0.8
```

This would ensure that your clock is bumped by -0.8 seconds compared to what it would otherwise have been synchronized to.

The edited time source configuration line would then look like this:

```
server 1.dk.pool.ntp.org iburst offset -0.8
```

If you're using "pool" instead of "server" the principle is the same.

Comment: It's even easier than that, see my answer...

Comment: Matter of opinion.  Personally, I'm not sure that a method requiring four images is easier than a one-line edit to a config file.  Even a WIMP like me finds command line easier sometimes.  (Window-Icon-Mouse Person)

Comment: @WGroleau I'm a command-line lover myself, but I have to admit that the GUI solution is much simpler in this case. And it's not 4 images, it's just two clicks. (although I'm not sure that solution is equivalent to yours, seems like the GUI solution notification message claims that it only sync once with offset then no longer sync? that's weird)

Comment: You might be right, but it sure took a lot more to explain.

Comment: @PaulCezanne The solutions are not the same. The GUI version disables time synchronization, the chrony.conf version will keep synchronization running and continuously apply the offset.

Comment: @PaulCezanne Your solution works, but will drift very quickly. Since you need high accuracy over a longer period time this one is a better solution. (Clock can drift as much as 1 second per hour if not being synchronized with a time-server.)

Comment: Except I don’t need it for a long time, maybe just a few hours. The latency changes over time, which is weird.

Comment: @PaulCezanne does the latency keep increasing or change randomly? I tried to offset audio via Bluetooth and via my onboard soundcard (on Linux) to make them match, and couldn't - there was a random factor of about up to about 100ms that changed whenever I restarted an audio stream.

Comment: I definitely have a random factor. I was 0.8 second one evening, next morning it was about 0.

Comment: @PaulCezanne, are you sure that your software correctly recognizes your offset from the rest of the world? Don't others see any offset when they run the app. I'd rather suspect the program you use that reports offset is not precise enough.

Additionally if the app you're using can properly identify offset, perhaps it can as well compensate for it. I have no idea what you're doing, would be curious to know more.

Comment: The program is WSJT-X. It could compensate for it but doesn't. I'm not sure why it doesn't. It is open source and my guess is that it was never just a priority. However, when you think about hundreds of instances running, all compensating for drift, you could get a chaotic system. The software is very precise, you need 0.5 second accuracy when running the FT4 digital mode.

Comment: https://wsjt.sourceforge.io

Comment: WSJT-X and MAP65 are open-source programs designed for weak-signal digital communication by amateur radio.  Normal usage requires a standard SSB transceiver and a personal computer with soundcard, or the equivalent.  SDR-style hardware including the SDR-IQ, Perseus, SoftRock, and FUNcube Dongle is supported by MAP65.  All of the programs are available free of charge, licensed under the GNU General Public License.  Installation packages for WSJT-X are available for Windows, Linux, and OS X, and MAP65 ais Windows only.

Answer (score 10):

You can offset the time using ChronyControl GUI.

Select "Step Time" from the pulldown menu.

[image]

Enter the amount of offset you need, here I'm setting 0.8 seconds.

[image]

Note, you time will be offset as you expected but it may drift. When you no longer need the offset just re-sync with the time server.

[image]

Ensure that restart chronic is checked

[image]

Comment: As far as I understood what you write here, this is a temporary measurement only. I.e. you step the time, but you then are no longer synchronized at all with time servers. The next time you synchronize with time servers, your clock will no longer be offset with 0.8 seconds. It is suitable for some, but just to note that for others it might be good with a "permanent" solution.

Comment: This is a one-off and the MacOS clock will drift quickly after setting this. A full second of drift per hour is not unusual. Which may be too much drift in the long run if your HAM sessions take longer than 30 minutes.

Comment: Oh fun, I should measure that!